# Is the iOS OTA 50Mb limit applying to all versions of iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, limit, ota

I haven't found a clear answer to this after a fair amount of scouring google and answers on here.

Our app being a mobile app gets a lot of sales from being able to, on a whim, be downloaded over 3G/Edge/Cellular because it is under the 20Mb limit (just).

We want to put in some more features but can't get any official confirmation if this is only for iOS 5.1 onwards, as in a hard coded limit for iOS5.1 devices (eg the New iPad) or it is remotely arbitrated from AppStore servers.

Probably leaning towards arbitrated from AppStore servers but at the moment either seem plausible.

eg. if someone has an iOS device running iOS version 5.0 or less AND has a 3G connection could you please try to download something big and free like 'Epic Citadel' over the 3G connection and let me know what the result is? The winner gets a well deserved virtual high five.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have personally experienced the new 50 MB limit (post March 7th, 2012), even on iOS 4.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes. Since introduction of The New iPad, the OTA limit was raised from 20 MB to 50 MB.

Comment: DJ Killcrazy got in first but still appreciate the clarification so you get upvoted too. :)